# VBA Saving to CurDir on Mapped Drive

Tags: excel, vba

I created a macro that needs some tweaking but cannot find an answer to one part. Based on the user input of officename, it opens up the SaveAs dialog box and creates a folder in the current directory of the file + today's date. When saved locally this works fine. When the file is moved to the mapped drive the save as dialog box opens to my local downloads folder. I've tried a few things but all have the same result.

When I debug and print the path it is correct. I believe the problem lies somewhere with how I'm using the FileSystemObject and the ChDir even though from what I've read these should be working fine the way they're being used. The complete sub is pasted below.

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim file_name As Variant
Dim xdir As String
Dim fso
Dim saveDate As String

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
saveDate = Date
saveDate = Replace(saveDate, "/", ".")
'Debug.Print "Test" & " "; officeName <-- good
Fname = officename & " " & Date
Fname = Replace(Fname, "/", "-")
Debug.Print Fname <-- good
xdir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & officename
Debug.Print xdir <-- good
If Not fso.FolderExists(xdir) Then
 fso.CreateFolder (xdir)
End If

ChDir (xdir)

' Get the file name.
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Fname, _
    FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook,*.xlsm,All Files,*.*", _
    Title:="Save As File Name")

' See if the user canceled.
If file_name = False Or "False.xls" Then Exit Sub
```

Comment: ChDir() doesn't work if the folder you're trying to switch to is on a different drive - you need to call ChDrive() first.  http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/chdrive.php

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Will add updated code for others to see.

Answer (score 0):

Updated code below is now working beautifully on all machines! Thanks for the input!

ChDir (xdir)

```
Sub SaveAs()
Dim file_name As Variant
Dim xdir As String
Dim fso
Dim saveDate As String
Dim driveLetter As String <-- NEW VARIABLE    

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
saveDate = Date
saveDate = Replace(saveDate, "/", ".")
'Debug.Print "Test" & " "; officeName <-- good
Fname = officename & " " & Date
Fname = Replace(Fname, "/", "-")
Debug.Print Fname <-- good
xdir = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & officename
Debug.Print xdir <-- good
If Not fso.FolderExists(xdir) Then
 fso.CreateFolder (xdir)
End If

////new code
driveLetter = Left(xdir, 1)
ChDrive (driveLetter)
////new code

ChDir (xdir)

' Get the file name.
file_name = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(Fname, _
FileFilter:="Excel Macro-Enabled Workbook,*.xlsm,All Files,*.*", _
Title:="Save As File Name")

' See if the user canceled.
If file_name = False Or "False.xls" Then Exit Sub
```